# Excel-formula: Replacing space with intra-word dashes except for intra-word dashes in place AND remove space between intra-word dashes

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been searching for an solution on Stackoverflow and experimenting in Excel for hours. I would like to know how to replace white space with intra-word dashes except for intra-word dashes already in place AND remove trailing and leading white space between intra-word dashes in excel. For example in an excel cell I have:

```
Frontline Topspot for dogs 89 - 132 lbs (12 Month Supply)
```

I would like to be converted into

```
Frontline-Topspot-for-dogs-89-132-lbs-(12-Month-Supply)
```

Any idea's? The purpose of this question is to apply the solution to my "product name" column in my product listings spreadsheet. Any ideas?

Comment: `experimenting in Excel for hours` please show what you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, would the following steps work?  Where the original is in cell A1:

=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-"," "))," ","-")

Or, in VBA,

```
Sub dashes()
stringA = "Frontline Topspot for dogs 89 - 132 lbs (12 Month Supply)"
stringB = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(stringA, "-", " ")
stringC = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(stringB)
stringD = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(stringC, " ", "-")
End Sub
```

Replacing existing dashes with spaces, trimming extra spaces, and replaces spaces with dashes?

Answer (score 1):

First, deal with the case of "foo - bar":

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1," - ", "-")
```

Then, deal with the cases of "foo bar":

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","-")
```

Now, put the two together:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," - ", "-")," ","-")
```

By first eliminating " - ", we now know that all remaining " "'s must be replaced with "-".

Answer (score 0):

type in next cell =SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","-")

Comment: That will do `89---132`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the spaces, anything with a "-" will now be ---

replace --- with "-"

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","-"),"---","-")
```

Comment: So I can use that formula in one step? [=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","-"),"---","-")]